# A movement requires 1 dimension, a rotation requires 2 dimensions, a what requires three dimensions?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

**Movement**
A zero-dimensional object cannot move. A one-dimensional object can move in one dimension (the x-axis). A two-dimensional object can move in two dimensions (the x-axis and y-axis). A three dimensional object can move in three dimensions (the x-, y-, and z-axis).

**In other words: There are *n* different ways for an n-dimensional object to move.**

**Rotation**
A zero- and a one-dimensional object cannot rotate. A two-dimensional object can rotate in one way (in the xy-plane). A three dimensional object can rotate in three ways (in the xy-, xz-, and yz-plane). And a four dimensional object can rotate in 6 ways (xy-, xz-, yz-, xw-, yw-, and zw-plane).

**In other words: There are *n(n-1)/2* different ways for an n-dimensional object to rotate.**

Now for the question, what do you call the next thing?

I do know that the next thing has some properties if you follow the same pattern. But I have no idea what it is and I was hoping you guys could help me out.

Here are some of the properties that I have extrapolated:

**The next thing**

A zero-, one- and two-dimensional object cannot do it. A three dimensional object can do it in one way (along xyz). A four dimensional object can do it in four ways (along xyz, xyw, xzw and yzw. And if you want to extrapolate further... an n-dimensional object can do it in *n(n-1)(n-2)/6* different ways.

So yeah, what do you call this thing?

Comment: Are you referring to something like hyperspherical propagation ? e.g., a hypersphere that is getting big and biger along the time axes ! ? :)

Comment: The generator of translations in $1$ dimension is $\epsilon_{i2}\partial/\partial x_i$. The generator of rotations in $2$ dimensions is $\epsilon_{ij3}x_i\partial/\partial x_j$. The next thing might have the generator $\epsilon_{ijk4}x_ix_j\partial/\partial x_k$ in three dimensions, but unfortunately that vanishes by antisymmetry. (Here $\epsilon$ is the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol).)

Comment: @joriki I do not know. I read the wikipedia article of that, but unfortunately, I do not understand it.

Comment: @Cardinal I don't think i'm referring to hyperspherical propagation, since that does have an application in one dimension. (as far as I know anyway). EDIT: Also, I think I am referring to only objects with spacial dimensions. I.e. where time isn't a dimension.

Comment: If you don't know about generators of transformations, one place to start might be the Wikipedia article on [infinitesimal transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_transformation). I'm not sure whether it's worth for you to delve into that, though, since my result was negative. That said, in case no one else comes up with a generalization that works, my argument might help explain why there isn't one. Very nice question, by the way.

Comment: What are the necessary properties of this "thing" that say a "thing" in one dimension can only be a translation ("movement")? Must the "thing" produce a "copy" of the original object? Must that copy preserve the distance between each pair of points of the object? Is the "thing" forbidden  to be a reflection? It would seem from your examples that the answers are all "yes", but perhaps I misunderstood you.

Comment: @DavidK the only restrictions are the combinations described above. (E.g. for the second "thing" (rotation) there should be n(n-1)/2 different ways for an n-dimensional object to do this second thing).  That is the only restriction. (And of course, for the third thing, there should be n(n-1)(n-2)/6 ways for an n-dimensional object to do this third thing). I edited the post to try to fix the clarity-issue

Comment: @DavidK I see your point now. Reflection would also count as the first "thing"

Comment: One way of interpreting your question is as follows. The Lie group $\mathbb R^n$ acts on $\mathbb R^n$ effectively and transitively (by translation); each has dimension $n$. The Lie group $O(n+1)$ acts on $S^n$ effectively and transitively by rotation; $O(n+1)$ has dimension $n(n+1)/2$. Is there an $n(n-1)(n-2)/6$-dimensional Lie group that acts effectively and transitively on some $n$-manifold? But it is a theorem of Montgomery and Zippin that a compact group $G$ acting transitively and effectively on a connected $n$-manifold can have dimension at most $n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: One counterintuitive property of four-dimensional objects is that they can rotate simultaneously around two separate axes.  How would you count that?

Comment: I disagree on the fact that a 0-dim object cannot move. Any parametrised curve in $R^n$, $n\geq 1$ describes the motion of a point ($0$ dim object) in time. In general an $n$ dimensional object $n \geq 0$ located in an $n$ dimensional manifold can move along any of the $n$ directions.

Comment: @Paul: I'm not quite satisfied with it: what about finite-dimensional, but not compact, groups? If I can find something that deals with that case soon I'll post it

Comment: @GFR Sorry, I think I meant: A zero-dimensional object in zero-dimensional space cannot move,  but I'm not sure if that satisfies the inequalities that you used, so you'll have to tell me.

Comment: @Paul Ok, you are thinking about the dimension of the ambient space, not of the object. I agree with you then!

Comment: I like Mike Miller comment. Trying other approaches, I imagine the first think is to understand what is special about translations and rotations and which spaces we want to consider. If we stick with $R^n$ with its natural inner product than translation and rotations are the only isometries so I guess no further generalisation is possible.

Comment: One could otherwise consider some more general Riemannian manifold, maybe of some special kind, say maximally symmetric, and asking if there is an embedded submanifold containing the orbit of a Killing vector, and if so what is the minimum dimension of this submanifold.

Comment: there are other ways of defining rotation. for example by reflection/mirroring, or by movement to different positions on a sphere (circle = 2 dimensional sphere). there are one-dimensional spheres and there are one dimensional reflections so in that way of thinking, there could be one dimensional rotation. there are also other ways of defining movement. for example the 2d-space of pixels on a computer is created from a 1-d space inside the computer's memory, each pixel has a single memory address. so every 2-d movement has a corresponding 1-d movement and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of interpreting this question is as follows:

The Lie group $\mathbb R^n$ acts effectively and transitively on the smooth manifold $\mathbb R^n$; each of these is $n$-dimensional. The special orthogonal group $SO(n+1)$ acts effectively and transitively on $S^n$; the former has dimension $n(n+1)/2$, and $S^n$ has dimension $n$.

Can we improve this? Are there, for instance, $n(n-1)(n-2)/6$-dimensional groups that act on $n$-dimensional manifolds?

If the group $G$ is compact, the answer is a firm *no*. It is a result of Montgomery and Zippin that a compact topological group acting effectively and transitively on a manifold of dimension $n$ must have dimension at most $n(n+1)/2$. If you want $G$ to be a Lie group acting smoothly, this is easier: first prove it if $G$ acts by isometries on a Riemannian manifold by induction; then if you have a transitive effective action on $M$, average the metric over $G$ to get a $G$-invariant metric on $M$, hence an action by isometries. That $G$ is compact is important here!

I don't know what bounds one has in the case that $G$ is non-compact - I'd like to hear from somebody if they do.